# weeklyOn() chaining in Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduling

May I chain weeklyOn() in Laravel 8 in next way?

```
$schedule->command('fill:institutes')
            ->weeklyOn(7, '18:00')
            ->weeklyOn(1, '18:00')
            ->weeklyOn(2, '18:00')
            ->weeklyOn(3, '18:00')
            ->weeklyOn(4, '18:00');
```

Answer (score 3):

No, only your last call `->weeklyOn(4, '18:00')` will be executed. According API docs, the first parameter supports an array, so you could try:

```
$schedule->command('fill:institutes')->weeklyOn([7,1,2,3,4], '18:00');
```

or:

```
$schedule->command('fill:institutes')->days([7,1,2,3,4])->at('18:00');
```